# Working on multiple git branches in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

The name inside the square brackets is the name of a GIT branch.
In this situation we have 2(!) names and i don't know why. 
One of the names is an existing branch (=>it is shown in the Git Repository View on the right), while the other name (=>boot) is nowhere to be found.

Has anyone seen something similar?
[image: Eclipse project view]

Comment: I can't find `boot` on the screenshot and the branches node of the repository is also collapsed. Can you clearify what you see? Generally, the label decoration shows `project-name [repo-name current-branch]`.

Comment: In the PACKAGE EXPLORER window (on the left) you can see :
**saps [boot][saps SAPS_1231....]**.
Whereas *saps = project name* and *SAPS_1231...= branch-name*

Comment: Ah, right, now I see it. The `[boot]` decoration does not come from the Git team provider. I assume it is drawn by the Spring Tool Suite and has got something to do with _Spring Boot_.

Comment: Maybe you are right,but the thing is that i didnt have that decoration, until after i created another Spring Boot Application in the same workspace.
Also that ruined my pom.xml and now it gives me an error
> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)